# What Jira role is required so as to have access to Jira import

Tags: import, jira, roles

I am a novice Jira user, part of a pilot project where none of us have notable experience. We are using hosted Jira. The site administrator has made me administrator of a couple of projects. Now I'd like to start by importing a backlog from an existing spreadsheet. I have prepared the CSV, but can nowhere find the "import" link mentioned in the documention, nor can I get to an Administration page such as I am seeing in YouTube videos. I am listed in "users and roles" as an administrator of the project in question, but I am not a site administrator, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The hint on your current permission actually matters. From the documentation:

> Log in to JIRA as a user with the *JIRA Administrators* global permission.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-csv-802592885.html

That said, the "Project Administrator" role will not suffice to do a CSV import.